# Check if ComponentRef implements an interface

Tags: angular, typescript

Suppose I have an interface

```
export interface IMyInterface {
  doStuff() : void;
  getStuff() : string;
}
```

And I also have a `private componentRef : ComponentRef<any>`.

How can I now check wether `this.componentRef.instance` is an implementation of `IMyInterface`? I searched around a lot and all I can find is checking whether an object has a member (e.g.)

```
private isMyInterface(object: any) : object is IMyInterface {
  return 'doStuff' in object;
}
```

But this approach has some serious implications.

1. It seems that this only works for properties, not for methods.
2. It implies that simply because `object` has such a member, it is of that type. It could also have a property `doStuff` but not because it implements the entire interface.
3. When we add or alter a method to `IMyInterface`, it would mean that we need also to rewrite the `isMyInterface` method.

So how could I get around solving **this problem to check for an interface implementation, not its field or properties**?

I also tried a 'hack'

```
export class Hacky() {}

export interface IMyInterface extends Hacky {
  ...
}

export class MyClass extends MyOtherClass implements IMyInterface {
  ...
}
```

to do an `instanceof`

```
// this.componentRef.instance is an IMyClass
return object instanceof Hacky
```

But resolves to false.

Comment: The question is why do you need this? Interfaces are gone as soon as you compile so you can't check for it the way you want to.

Comment: Because I show a component within a dialog (this component can also be shown regularly outside a dialog). But if this component is shown in a dialog and has the interface `IDialogable`, we need to do some stuff. I know that this is by far the cleanest approach. But also as a theoretical question. Other languages allow this e.g. C#: `void MyFunction(object obj) { if (obj is IMyInterface) {...} }`

Comment: Yeah but those languages differ drastically from javascript I'm afraid. I would suggest using an enum value or something to determine what you should do.